# How to change the request path in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

Im trying to integrate [PhotoSwipe](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html) into my current Project

## this is the webpack.config.js

```
module.exports =
{
    entry: './input.js',
    output:
    {
        path: 'js/',
        filename: 'output.js'
    },
    resolve:
    {
        alias:
        {
            'photoswipe_js': './node_modules/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.js',
            'photoswipe_ui_default': './node_modules/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.js'
        }
    },
    watch: true
};
```

this is my main file

```
require(['photoswipe_js', 'photoswipe_ui_default'], function( PhotoSwipe, PhotoSwipeUI_Default )
{
    console.log(PhotoSwipe);
    console.log(PhotoSwipeUI_Default);
});
```

[image]

for some reason its trying to find the compiled file from the project root
like

`'/1.output.js'`

I need it to try to fetch the output file from

```
'/bundles/mybundle/js/1.output.js'
```

instead, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Add **publicPath** to your *output* object :

```
module.exports =
{
  ...
  output:
  {
    path: 'js/',
    filename: 'output.js',
    publicPath: '/bundles/mybundle/js/'
  },
  ...
};
```